# Storing a string into a property

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my class, we are just starting object-oriented Python (we were doing functional programming since the beginning of the semester).

> Write a new class called Sentence with the following methods:
>   An `__init__` method which takes a single parameter for a sentence as a string and stores this string in a property. Assume the sentence has no punctuation.
>   A `get_words` method which returns the number of words in the sentence. Hint: `split`.
>   A capitalize method which modifies the property to make sure the first letter is capitalized. Nothing is returned. Hint: upper but only to the first character.

I'm confused on the init method portion. What does it mean by "store this string in a property".

Also, irrelevant to this hmwk assignment, but why do we call the function **init**? Is it sort of like the "main" function like in C programming (I come from a C background).

Comment: Whoever wrote your book or course notes or whatever doesn't seem to know Python very well. They almost certainly want you to store the string in an [_attribute_](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-attribute). A [_property_](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) is a completely different thing, which novices shouldn't even be hearing about.

Comment: Meanwhile, if your class/book/tutorial isn't very helpful, you may want to look at the official Python tutorial. For example, [Class Objects](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) explains almost everything you're asking here, with helpful links to more details, in less than a page of text and examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, you can add [attributes](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-attribute) to objects at any time. For example:

```
class Sentence(object):
    pass

sentence = Sentence()
sentence.the_string = "This is a sentence."
```

An `__init__` method is a special method that gets called when you construct an instance of the class. For example, that `Sentence()` ends up calling `__init__` with no extra arguments. Because I didn't define any `__init__`, I get the default, which does nothing. But now let's define one, and give it an extra parameter:

```
class Sentence(object):
    def __init__(self, the_sentence):
        pass

sentence = Sentence("This is a sentence.")
sentence.the_string = "This is a different sentence."
```

Now, the only thing left is moving that attribute creation into the `__init__` method:

```
class Sentence(object):
    def __init__(self, the_sentence):
        self.the_string = the_sentence

sentence = Sentence("This is a sentence.")
```

---

The actual question asked about storing the string in a *[property](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)* instead of an *attribute*. This is almost certainly not part of what you're actually supposed to learn, but rather a sign that your instructor or textbook or tutorial writer doesn't actually know Python very well. A `property` is a way of *faking* normal attributes on top of methods, which you shouldn't be learning about any time soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Those are my professors notes. he's from the mathematical department so he probably doesn't know the terms as much as a CS professor would. Also one last question. When I go to test it out using sentence = Sentence("This is a sentence.") do I have to call all other methods I want to use in the __init__ function?

Comment: For example: do I have to do print get_words(self) in the __init__ function if I wanted to print the result of get_words?

Comment: @juice: That depends. Do you want constructing a `Sentence` object to always automatically call `get_words`, and `print` the result? If so, then do it in the `__init__` method. If not, don't, and instead call it where you want it to be called.

Comment: @juice: Also, that's not how you call a method in Python. It's `self.get_words()`, not `get_words(self)`.

Comment: okay I understand now. Thanks a lot. It's similar to a struct in C. I appreciate it. But yea I want it to print out the result everytime for each method. Thanks again.

Comment: @juice: It's _similar_ to a struct. The big difference is that in C, you have to _declare_ all the members of a struct in the class definition, as well as having to set the values somewhere; in Python, just setting the values somewhere is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

"Store this string in a property" means a property of a class, like so:

```
class Sentence(object):
    def __init__(self, sentence):
        self.my_sentence = sentence
```

In any function that's a member of this class (and that takes `self` as a parameter), including `__init__`, you can refer to `my_sentence` as "`self.my_sentence`".

Python's "special" functions are all prefixed and suffixed with `__`. The function is called `__init__` because it's the initializer for that class, called when you instantiate a class object. For example, if you did `Sentence(foo, bar)`, you'd be calling `Sentence`'s  `__init__` method with `foo` and `bar` as arguments.

Comment: This is almost certainly _not_ the right answer. You're storing `my_sentence` as a _class_ attribute, not an _instance_ attribute. Since they're supposed to be storing it in `__init__`, this can't possibly be what they want.

Comment: Sure, you have to set it in the `__init__` function. I didn't want to give away the whole exercise...

Comment: But you cannot set a class attribute in the `__init__` method. If you try, what you end up doing is creating a separate instance attribute with the same name that hides the class attribute.

Comment: Your edited version is even more wrong; it's now just creating a local variable named `my_sentence`, which is forgotten as soon as the method returns.

Comment: @abarnert Sorry, it's been a long night. Fixed.